# Create live video of jpeg snapshots using Gstreamer and JavaScript setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to create a live "video" stream using an  tag on a web page.

A Gstreamer pipeline continually overwrites a file "snapshot.jpeg" with a new frame grabbed from a webcam using video4linux2 with a framerate of 15 fps.

A web page renders the image without caching every 100 ms.

The problem is that I get **ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH** (in browser console) for the image source on many frames. This is shown as a broken link in the browser.

**GStreamer 0.10 syntax**

```
gst-launch v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480, framerate=15/1 ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=/var/www/video/snapshot.jpeg
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8' />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <img id="snapshot" src="snapshot.jpeg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    function refreshImage(){
    $("#snapshot").attr("src", 'snapshot.jpeg?' + Math.random());
    setTimeout(refreshImage, 100);
    }
    refreshImage();
})
```

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Lighttpd 1.4.33 together with HAProxy 1.4

Comment: On which System? My first guess was that `multifilesink` keeps overwriting the same file and the web server ends up reading unfinished versions of the files. But it seems that `multifilesink` does it right and writes to temporary files that replace `snapshot.jpeg` once they're written. At least that what's happening on my system (gst-0.10.36, Debian jessie). but your example code seems to work flawlessly here

Comment: Ubuntu 12.4. Have you tested in Chrome as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to hook setTimeout to Image.onload:

```
$(function() {
    function refreshImage(){
        $("#snapshot").attr("src", 'snapshot.jpeg?' + Math.random());
    }
    $("#snapshot").onload = function(){
        setTimeout(refreshImage, 100);
    }
    refreshImage();
})
```

Comment: I actually made it inline javascript which calls refreshImage() directly without setTimeout(). This works in Firefox and IE10+ but not in Chrome. I will use another method for Chrome I think.

Comment: Yes, it's also fine, as soon as you use img.onload event. The only concern here may be the load on the server, shorter the delay - higher the load.