# Showing live camera streaming window in angularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, gstreamer, live-streaming, ip-camera

I am working in a Angular and Java project, where I need to show my camera live (camera added using IP) in my web page (developed in angular). I heard G streaming can help me on this but I did not found any helpful link for this.

I am wondering if G-streaming is only the way to show the camera live streaming or is there any thing else I can do.

Any help would a great help.

As this will be a demo so I have very little knowledge on this, please ask if any doubt.

**UPDATE:**

I need to ready a demo where I can put my camera's IP and it will show live in my webpage developed in angular.

Answer (score 2):

just few infos until your question is closed ..

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385516/create-live-video-of-jpeg-snapshots-using-gstreamer-and-javascript-settimeout)

And [this](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets)

I think that you can stream the camera with Gstreamer [rtsp server](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-rtsp-server.html)
 implementation and open up that [web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page) if I understand that properly..

HTH